# errores en paginas que visito

Tags: web

estoy visitando una pagina web la cual necesito para descargar un archivo y me aparece un error quiero saber que sera no soy deuño de lapagina solo soy visitante, este es:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:483) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:592) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:526) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:887) at org.apache.jsp.layouts.maquetado.estilo_jsp._jspService(estilo_jsp.java:168) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) at controladores.ControladorResultados.despachar(ControladorResultados.java:1157) at controladores.ControladorResultados.enviarCorreo(ControladorResultados.java:232) at controladores.ControladorResultados.processRequest(ControladorResultados.java:131) at controladores.ControladorResultados.doPost(ControladorResultados.java:1129) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pero como intentas descargar el archivo, que medios usas para querer descargarlo tienes que ser un poco mas especifico amigo. También usa las herramientas de formato de texto que te brinda el sitio.

Comment: está mal hecha la página; está esperando un dato  a usar en la generación del archivo y lo recibe nulo.

Comment: @andres Mírate este post [Java NullPointerException](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-lang-nullpointerexception) por si quieres profundizar mas en el tema.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].